# Why my react native vector icons are not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Why my react native vector icons are not working? I tried following every step in the react-native vector icons docs said but still, my icons are not working can anyone can help me how can I setup it up properly? i want to use a camera icon in my app so i tried this `import { Entypo } from 'react-native-vector-icons';` and then `\<Entypo name="camera" size={24} color="black" style={icons1} /\>` but when it was giving me exports error I also tried to use `import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';` and then `\<Icon name="camera-outline" size={24} color="black" style={icons1}/\>` but still the export errors due to it and when I remove those icons the error is gone,

is there any website where i can see all the react-native-vector-icons for react native cli app and also i can see the code snippet for usage?

i also added this in the android/settings.gradle file:

```
include ':react-native-vector-icons' project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
```

then added this in android/app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {     ...     implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons') }
```

and lastly, I added this in MainApplication.java:

```java
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;

@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
    ...
    new VectorIconsPackage()
    );
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to run app again?

Comment: @VickyAhuja yep i did

Comment: try to recheck all the steps specified in repo

Comment: did you followed the applied from step available docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Frist thing**

you can install vector icons using this npm

```
react-native-vector-icons
```

then done all the setup from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons)

then after you can import like this

```
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
```

- many times vector icons [icons] do not work in our system
- so you can use different icons in vector icons many different icons
  part in vector icon

here is Exmplae maybe this will help you

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FontAwesome name="rocket" size={30} color="#900" />
      <FontAwesome name="home" size={30} color="#b2b2b2" />
      <FontAwesome name="facebook" size={30} color="#900" />
      <FontAwesome name="google" size={30} color="#000" />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 8,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

[here is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/httVZ.png)